# how to retrieve git build data from jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I'm trying to retrieve the Git Build Data from jenkins pipeline and sent the details by mail

Is there any API or inbuilt variable available?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [GitLab APIs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html) for this. Also, check [Gitlab CLI](https://glab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline/status.html) as well.